# How to print columns from file with delimiter?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

From:

```
pa: Pensilvania:145
mo:Misuri:50
va:Virginia:20
```

Print1:

```
pa:
mo:
va:
```

Print2:

```
pa: Pensilvania
mo: Misuri
va:Virginia
```

`sed` or `cut` will be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk -F: '{print $1 FS}' file
pa:
mo:
va:
```

and

```
$ awk -F: '{print $1 FS $2}' file
pa: Pensilvania
mo:Misuri
va:Virginia
```

---

If you prefer `cut`, the second one is straightforward:

```
$ cut -d: -f1,2 file
pa: Pensilvania
mo:Misuri
va:Virginia
```

To get the trailing delimiter that you want in the first case, you could use `paste`:

```
$ cut -d: -f1 file | paste -d: - /dev/null
pa:
mo:
va:
```

OTOH this one *is* easy with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/:.*/:/' file
pa:
mo:
va:
```

while the second takes a bit more thought:

```
$ sed 's/:[^:]*//2' file
pa: Pensilvania
mo:Misuri
va:Virginia
```

Comment: Beat me to it!  =)  +1

Comment: Nice! thank you but I would prefer sed or cut if it can be, I forgot to indicate it, I just edited it now sorry.

Comment: @TheTourist please see updated answer